# Refresh only the current nav tab in bootstrap which contains iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I'm using nav tab for bootstrap, I have 3 tabs and each tab shows iframe that displays page.
 I noticed that the three pages related to each tabs are updated only one time (the first visit to the main page). Later  when I move from tab to another, the tabs are not updated. I want the page displayed in iframe to be updated once the tab cliked because it reads data from database and I need it to be up-to-date.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <iframe src="Page1.aspx" style="width:100%; height:850px ; border:none";  id="frame1"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <iframe src="Page2.aspx" style="width:100%; height:850px ; border:none";  id="frame2"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
   <iframe src="Page3.aspx" style="width:100%; height:850px ; border:none";  id="frame3"></iframe>
</div>
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function refresh(val){
  document.getElementById( '#' + val).contentWindow.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <iframe src="Page1.aspx" style="width:100%; height:850px ; border:none";  id="frame1" onclick="refresh('frame1')"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <iframe src="Page2.aspx" style="width:100%; height:850px ; border:none";  id="frame2" 
    onclick="refresh('frame1')"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
   <iframe src="Page3.aspx" style="width:100%; height:850px ; border:none";  id="frame3" onclick="refresh('frame1')"></iframe>
</div>
```

On click call refresh function and pass id.
//This statement will refresh the Iframe.
document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, the iframe didn't reload again

Comment: Please find it here, https://plnkr.co/edit/RVKJYCANYtCurnfhveWY?p=preview , in the iframe inside menu 2 for example: if I click one link from the right menu such as "Tables" and then I go to Menu1, and come back to Menu2, it shows the page on "Tables", it doesn't change.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Please Refer https://plnkr.co/edit/Jexv8u?p=preview

Comment: I tried it and the iframes still not updated. when I'm in Menu 2 for example which its iframe goes to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#images , it's is showing the "images" part in the given link and if I clicked another link from the right menu, for example "using less", and I go to menu 1 and then click back on Menu2, the link does not return to images part as the original link "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#images ", it keeps displaying "using less" that I clicked the last time I was in Menu2 tab.